# strapi graphql limit only return 100 items even if I set limit to -1

Tags: graphql, strapi

currently I have some problem with strapi graphql query. I can only query about 100 items max.

here is my query:
`query StudioList { studios(limit: -1) { id slug name } }`

with or without limit always return 100 items. how do i query for more than 100?
thanks..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution (this is for old version, 2020 version, i don't remember):
if you have plugins.js file in your strapi ./config folder, then add the following code:

```
module.exports = {
  //
  graphql: {
    endpoint: '/graphql',
    shadowCRUD: true,
    playgroundAlways: false,
    depthLimit: 7,
    amountLimit: 2500,
    apolloServer: {
      tracing: false,
    },
  },
};
```

change the amountlimit to whatever you want..
then restart the server, now it should shows more than 100 items.

Comment: For an older (v3 beta) version of Strapi I found these settings to reside in `node_modules/strapi-plugin-graphql/config/settings.json`

Answer (score 0):

I try with version of strap 3.6.8 but that's doesn't work. I rebuild strapi "npm build" & "yarn develop"

```
module.exports = {
  //
  graphql: {
    endpoint: '/graphql',
    shadowCRUD: true,
    playgroundAlways: false,
    depthLimit: 7,
    amountLimit: 2500,
    apolloServer: {
      tracing: false,
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Strapi v4 (with TypeScript) and none of these solutions worked for me. I must mention that I am using custom GraphQL resolvers though.

What did work for me was changing the `defaultLimit` and `maxLimit` in this file `config/api.ts`

the file looks like this:

```
export default {
  rest: {
    defaultLimit: 1000,
    maxLimit: 2000,
    withCount: true,
  },
};
```